# Timer fired twice when running Windows service

Tags: c#, timer, duplicates

When the service is running the program runs twice. The average running time is 10 minutes.

```
private void InitializeTimer()
{
    var confcontr = new ConfigurationController();
    var config = confcontr.ReadConfiguration();

    try
    {
        if (serviceTimer != null)
        {
            serviceTimer.AutoReset = true;

            Articles art = new Articles(config);

            //Conexion a a los articulos de BD para obtener parametros de iniciación 
            serviceTimer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(60*1000)* art.Parameter();

            //Se especifica cada que tanto tiempo se ejecuta el servicio
            serviceTimer.Enabled = true;
            serviceTimer.Elapsed += serviceTimer_Elapsed;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Log.Instance.WriteToLog(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + "initializetimer");
    }
}
```

This is the method I'm calling

```
protected void serviceTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var artcont = new ArticulosController();
    artcont.EjecutarArticulo();
}
```

Comment: Is InitializeTimer() called only once in your code? Are there any other event handlers assigned to Elapsed?

Comment: No, the initializeTimer() is only called once, and is the only handler i´m using.

Comment: Do you run your own thread pool? If so, are the timers outside of the  "threaded" code?

Answer (score 0):

The timer will execute the `Elapsed` event asynchronously by raising the event using a ThreadPool thread, so it can overlap.

Instead turn off `AutoReset` and try something like:

```
protected void serviceTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var artcont = new ArticulosController();
    artcont.EjecutarArticulo();

    ((Timer)sender).Start();
}
```

This will restart the timer once the current `Elapsed` event has finished.

Comment: Enabled = true is the same as Start().

Comment: Is there a difference between setting AutoReset to false and calling `.Stop()` at the top of the event handler?

Comment: @adam0101 Not really, it just saves the extra call as with `AutoReset` off you don't explicitly need to stop it.

Comment: @Danielopez.. Need more details then, when/how is `InitializeTimer` called?

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your method to construct the timer. Event subscriptions without any protection are likely to get subscribed more than once. This is especially true as you use your code outside your class or other developers use it. As an alternative, you could also put an isInitialzed variable in place. Use lock(s) if it needs to be thread safe. Use a Mutex if it needs protection from other processes. If the Elapsed method is long running, stop the timer and restart it when finished so the events don't 'pile-up'. During initialization, start the timer after adding the subscription.

```
private void InitializeTimer()
{
    var confcontr = new ConfigurationController();
    var config = confcontr.ReadConfiguration();

    try
    {
        if (serviceTimer == null)
        {
            serviceTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

            serviceTimer.AutoReset = true;

            Articles art = new Articles(config);

            //Conexion a a los articulos de BD para obtener parametros de iniciación 
            serviceTimer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(60 * 1000) * art.Parameter();

            //Se especifica cada que tanto tiempo se ejecuta el servicio
            serviceTimer.Elapsed += serviceTimer_Elapsed;
            serviceTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Instance.WriteToLog(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + "initializetimer");
    }
}

protected void serviceTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    serviceTimer.Enabled = false;

    try
    {
        var artcont = new ArticulosController();
        artcont.EjecutarArticulo();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Instance.WriteToLog(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + "serviceTimer_Elapsed");
    }

    serviceTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```